# Azure obtain a SAS token to query Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have Azure VM with system level managed identity. The identity has read/write/delete permissions on a Storage Queue. From VM, I use az cli to try and list messsage in queue such as:

```
az storage message peek -q queue --account-name storageacct
```

I error that I must provide a SAS token to authenticate.

Does az not know the VM has a managed identity or do i somehow use the identity to obtain a token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login first, using

```
az login --identity
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-sign-in#azure-cli